# Extracting data from satellite tiff file in .nc format?

Tags: qgis, landsat-8

I'm working with Landsat-8 satellite images and sometimes I need to open real values (numbers) for example as a simple excel table (or similar).

These my steps for getting TOA reflection in QGIS:

1. using semi-automatic-classification plugin - I built the reflected bands
2. create raster
3. convert it to .nc file

But how can I be sure, that values are really represent data (in .nc file) that I need?